# Progress Bar in ajax while uploading 2 files or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

Hi Im trying to upload a 2 file or more, my problem is my progress bar will say 100% because of the small file being uploaded first, then its going back to the percent of the large file.. My question is how can I have a same progress if i have many files being uploaded?

```
$('body').on('change', 'input:file.gallery_images', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('id', $("#id").val());

    var count = $(this)[0].files.length;

    $.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file)
    {
        data.append('userfile', file);

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: href+path+"/imagens/store",
            data: data,
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            xhr: function()
            {
                var _xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                _xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (event) { }, false);

                if (_xhr.upload) 
                {
                    _xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) 
                    {
                        var percent = 0;
                        if (event.lengthComputable) 
                        {
                            var position = event.position || event.loaded;
                            var total = event.totalSize || event.total;
                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                        }
                        $("#progress-bar").width(percent + '%');

                    };
                }
                return _xhr;
            },
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#progress").fadeIn('slow');
                $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.gallery)
                {
                    if($(".alert").length > 0) 
                    {
                        $(".alert").hide('slow').remove();
                        $("#droppable").show('slow');
                    }
                    $('.gallery').fadeTo('300', '0.5', function () {
                        $(this).html($(this).html() + data.gallery).fadeTo('300', '1');
                    });
                }
                $("#progress").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing I noticed is that you're adding the file to the 'data' variable inside your $.each... but that means the first POST contains the first image, the second POST contains the first and the second, and so on. I think you should this part inside your $.each:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('id', $("#id").val());
```

Ok, so, to solve your problem: Before sending anything, go through them and sum their size. You'll also need to store the progress for each file individually, so start it as zero:

```
var sumTotal = 0;
var loaded = [];
for (var i = 0, list = $(this)[0].files; i < list.length; i++) {
   sumTotal += list[i].size;
   loaded[i] = 0;
}
```

Inside your onprogress, instead of comparing the event.position with the event.totalSize, you'll store this position on your 'loaded' array, sum all your array, and then compare it to your sumTotal.

```
loaded[i] = event.position || event.loaded;
var sumLoaded = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < loaded.length; j++) sumLoaded += loaded[j];
percent = Math.ceil(sumLoaded * 100/sumTotal);
```

;)

Comment: The 'id' that I send is the same for all. This method didn't work. The same thing happens. Only once the bars appers.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvote either, but it's worth bearing in mind that it's not worth asking about voting decisions - voters will have long since moved on. For that reason, and since most readers don't log in or vote, we would rather voting commentary is not edited into posts here. If you really want to ask about it, keep it to the comments, though at best you'll get guesses from people who did not vote.